Hive - data not importing nor inserting
I am using Hadoop 3.3.5 and Hive 4.0.0 that uses Tez and Postgres on VirtualBox on a ubuntu server image. I can load data into HDFS /datasets/ In Hive I can create tables, and load in data to the tables successfully. I am logged into hive as:
beeline -u jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default -u hive -p hive
When I run a SELECT statement I receive following error message:
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default> select * from flights_ext limit 10;
Error: Error running query (state=,code=0)

I have checked the privileges for hive, and received this response below. I suspect this might be causing the issue but cannot resolve this issue. It specifies I am using anonymous as a user.
INFO  : Executing command(queryId=hallam_20240625104738_001fad6e-e1cd-4909-846c-2b478fd35bba): show roles
INFO  : Starting task [Stage-0:DDL] in serial mode
ERROR : Failed
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.plugin.HiveAccessControlException: Current user : anonymous is not allowed to list roles. User has to belong to ADMIN role and have it as current role, for this action.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.plugin.sqlstd.SQLStdHiveAccessController.getAllRoles(SQLStdHiveAccessController.java:341) ~[hive-exec-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.plugin.sqlstd.SQLStdHiveAccessControllerWrapper.getAllRoles(SQLStdHiveAccessControllerWrapper.java:132) ~[hive-exec-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.plugin.HiveAuthorizerImpl.getAllRoles(HiveAuthorizerImpl.java:98) ~[hive-exec-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.ddl.privilege.role.show.ShowRolesOperation.execute(ShowRolesOperation.java:42) ~[hive-exec-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.ddl.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:84) ~[hive-exec-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:214) ~[hive-exec-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:105) ~[hive-exec-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Executor.launchTask(Executor.java:354) ~[hive-exec-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Executor.launchTasks(Executor.java:327) ~[hive-exec-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Executor.runTasks(Executor.java:244) ~[hive-exec-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Executor.execute(Executor.java:105) ~[hive-exec-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:367) ~[hive-exec-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:205) ~[hive-exec-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:154) ~[hive-exec-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:149) ~[hive-exec-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.reexec.ReExecDriver.run(ReExecDriver.java:185) ~[hive-exec-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runQuery(SQLOperation.java:236) ~[hive-service-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.access$500(SQLOperation.java:90) ~[hive-service-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$BackgroundWork$1.run(SQLOperation.java:336) ~[hive-service-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_412]
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) ~[?:1.8.0_412]
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1899) ~[hadoop-common-3.3.5.jar:?]
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$BackgroundWork.run(SQLOperation.java:356) ~[hive-service-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_412]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_412]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_412]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_412]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) ~[?:1.8.0_412]
ERROR : DDLTask failed, DDL Operation: class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.ddl.privilege.role.show.ShowRolesOperation
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.plugin.HiveAccessControlException: Current user : anonymous is not allowed to list roles. User has to belong to ADMIN role and have it as current role, for this action.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.plugin.sqlstd.SQLStdHiveAccessController.getAllRoles(SQLStdHiveAccessController.java:341) ~[hive-exec-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.plugin.sqlstd.SQLStdHiveAccessControllerWrapper.getAllRoles(SQLStdHiveAccessControllerWrapper.java:132) ~[hive-exec-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.plugin.HiveAuthorizerImpl.getAllRoles(HiveAuthorizerImpl.java:98) ~[hive-exec-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.ddl.privilege.role.show.ShowRolesOperation.execute(ShowRolesOperation.java:42) ~[hive-exec-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.ddl.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:84) ~[hive-exec-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:214) ~[hive-exec-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:105) ~[hive-exec-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Executor.launchTask(Executor.java:354) ~[hive-exec-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Executor.launchTasks(Executor.java:327) ~[hive-exec-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Executor.runTasks(Executor.java:244) ~[hive-exec-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Executor.execute(Executor.java:105) ~[hive-exec-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:367) ~[hive-exec-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:205) ~[hive-exec-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:154) ~[hive-exec-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:149) ~[hive-exec-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.reexec.ReExecDriver.run(ReExecDriver.java:185) ~[hive-exec-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runQuery(SQLOperation.java:236) ~[hive-service-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.access$500(SQLOperation.java:90) ~[hive-service-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$BackgroundWork$1.run(SQLOperation.java:336) ~[hive-service-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_412]
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) ~[?:1.8.0_412]
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1899) ~[hadoop-common-3.3.5.jar:?]
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$BackgroundWork.run(SQLOperation.java:356) ~[hive-service-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_412]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_412]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_412]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_412]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) ~[?:1.8.0_412]
ERROR : FAILED: Execution Error, return code 40000 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.ddl.DDLTask. Current user : anonymous is not allowed to list roles. User has to belong to ADMIN role and have it as current role, for this action.
INFO  : Completed executing command(queryId=hallam_20240625104738_001fad6e-e1cd-4909-846c-2b478fd35bba); Time taken: 0.031 seconds
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 40000 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.ddl.DDLTask. Current user : anonymous is not allowed to list roles. User has to belong to ADMIN role and have it as current role, for this action. (state=08S01,code=40000)
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default>

UPDATE 26/06:
I created a table in Hive, then did SELECT and it worked. When I tried to insert data it threw this error:
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default> describe test;
INFO  : Compiling command(queryId=hallam_20240625233818_62130799-6600-4a44-85c2-ce0b49395f00): describe test
INFO  : Semantic Analysis Completed (retrial = false)
INFO  : Created Hive schema: Schema(fieldSchemas:[FieldSchema(name:col_name, type:string, comment:from deserializer), FieldSchema(name:data_type, type:string, comment:from deserializer), FieldSchema(name:comment, type:string, comment:from deserializer)], properties:null)
INFO  : Completed compiling command(queryId=hallam_20240625233818_62130799-6600-4a44-85c2-ce0b49395f00); Time taken: 0.06 seconds
INFO  : Concurrency mode is disabled, not creating a lock manager
INFO  : Executing command(queryId=hallam_20240625233818_62130799-6600-4a44-85c2-ce0b49395f00): describe test
INFO  : Starting task [Stage-0:DDL] in serial mode
INFO  : Completed executing command(queryId=hallam_20240625233818_62130799-6600-4a44-85c2-ce0b49395f00); Time taken: 0.144 seconds
+-----------+------------+----------+
| col_name  | data_type  | comment  |
+-----------+------------+----------+
| name      | string     |          |
+-----------+------------+----------+
1 row selected (0.381 seconds)
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default> select * from test;
INFO  : Compiling command(queryId=hallam_20240625233829_6a74d64d-ce9a-4a1a-8809-6492aba9ba49): select * from test
INFO  : No Stats for default@test, Columns: name
INFO  : Semantic Analysis Completed (retrial = false)
INFO  : Created Hive schema: Schema(fieldSchemas:[FieldSchema(name:test.name, type:string, comment:null)], properties:null)
INFO  : Completed compiling command(queryId=hallam_20240625233829_6a74d64d-ce9a-4a1a-8809-6492aba9ba49); Time taken: 0.299 seconds
INFO  : Concurrency mode is disabled, not creating a lock manager
INFO  : Executing command(queryId=hallam_20240625233829_6a74d64d-ce9a-4a1a-8809-6492aba9ba49): select * from test
INFO  : Completed executing command(queryId=hallam_20240625233829_6a74d64d-ce9a-4a1a-8809-6492aba9ba49); Time taken: 0.001 seconds
+------------+
| test.name  |
+------------+
+------------+
No rows selected (0.391 seconds)
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default> INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Alice'), ('Bob'), ('Charlie');
Error: Error running query (state=,code=0)
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default>

Please can you help resolve the issue.
